# Use setTimeout to periodically make autocomplete AJAX calls?

Tags: jquery, settimeout, javascript

I would like to use a setTimeout function so that Ajax calls are only made at the most every 1 second.

Here is what I have. This is clearly not correct, but I am not sure how the setTimeout function works.

```
function autoComplete(q, succ)
{

    setTimeout(

    if(q != "") {
        $.ajax({type:"GET",
            url: "php/search.php",
            data: "q="+q,
            success: succ
        });
    }

    , 1000);
}
```

I think that I should use clearTimeout so that if another call is made, it will reset the timer and wait another 1 second, but when I tried to implement this it stopped running the function.

Comment: I'm not even sure what you are trying to achieve. Take a step back and think about the problem you're trying to solve. You start an ajax call: it goes ahead. You immediately start another before the first completes: what should happen to it? Should it fail with a "it's been less than a second" error? Should it get queued to be executed one second later? What if I queue 1000 of these before a second is up: do you want a queue of 1000 waiting ajax calls? Aren't they going to "decay" in a sense: the data they're requesting is no longer needed? Somehow I don't think setTimeout is the issue.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Pass a ... function :)

Using an anonymous function might be as follows:

```
var timeoutId
function autoComplete(q, succ)
{
    if (q) {
        // stop previous timeouts
        clearTimeout(timeoutId)
        timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
            $.ajax({type:"GET",
                url: "php/search.php",
                data: "q="+q,
                success: succ
            });
         }, 1000);
    }
}
```

Note I move the check for `q` outside. This won't run two timeouts at once, but **there may be multiple in-flight requests**. To guard against this, the `success` callback needs a guard -- and a simple way to do this is with a counter. Checking the "current q" with the `q` in the `setTimeout` may lead to subtle race conditions.

```
var timeoutId
var counter = 0
function autoComplete(q, succ)
{
    if (q) {
        // Increment counter to maintain separate versions
        counter++
        var thisCounter = counter
        clearTimeout(timeoutId)
        timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
            $.ajax({type:"GET",
                url: "php/search.php",
                data: "q="+q,
                success: function () {
                    // Only call success if this is the "latest"
                    if (counter == thisCounter) {
                       succ.apply(this, arguments)
                    }
                },
            });
         }, 1000);
    }
}
```

A smarter version might read the *current* value at time of submission because **the above code will always lag one second behind...**

Now, imagine `getQ` is a function object...

```
var timeoutId
var counter = 0
function autoComplete(getQ, succ)
{
    counter++
    var thisCounter = counter
    clearTimeout(timeoutId)
    timeoutId = setTimeout(function () {
        var q = getQ() // get the q ... NOW
        if (q) {
            $.ajax({type:"GET",
                url: "php/search.php",
                data: "q="+q,
                success: function () {
                    if (counter == thisCounter) {
                       succ.apply(this, arguments)
                    }
                },
            });
         }
     }, 1000);
}

// example usage
autoComplete(function () { return $(elm).val() }, successCallback)
```

Happy coding.

---

One thing to consider, not addressed in the above, is that there **may still be multiple in-flight requests** (the guard in the 2nd example only shows how to "throw out" old responses, not how to limit requests appropriately). This can be handled with a short-queue and prevention of submitting a new AJAX request until either the reply is obtained or a sufficient "timeout" has expired and the request is considered invalid.

Comment: Thank you. Your response is more than I could have asked for. This will help me tons.

Comment: Why is this answer not rated higher? ... much higher!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way also,

```js
var textInput = document.getElementById('input');
var timeout = null; // default set
textInput.onkeyup = function (e) {

    // If it has already been set cleared first.
    clearTimeout(timeout);

    // set timeout to 500ms
    timeout = setTimeout(function () {
        console.log('Input Value:', textInput.value);
    }, 500);
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="input">
```